# How to check if text node of xml file has a child node inside and get all data from them?

Tags: c#, xml, text, xmlreader

I have xml file. This is just piece of that file

```
1    <mainTerm>
2      <title> Abandonment </title>
3      <see> Maltreatment </see>
4    </mainTerm>
5    <mainTerm>
6      <title> Abasia <nemod>(-astasia) (hysterical) </nemod></title>
7      <code>F44.4</code>
8    </mainTerm>
```

I have a lot of `<mainTerm>` and i loop through all of them. I copy all data of elements, but when i reach line 6, i got the problem. How to copy all that content? I need get at the end string, that will looks like "Abasia (-astasia) (hysterical)".

That's the piece of my app that work with that file

```
     List<string> nodes = new List<string>();

            //Create XmlReaderSettings object
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;

            //Create XmlReader object
            XmlReader xmlIn = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("mainTerm"))
{
 do
 {
   xmlIn.ReadStartElement("mainTerm");                                                  

   nodes.Add(xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString());                          

   nodes.Add(xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString());                          

 } while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("mainTerm"));
}
```

Comment: Be careful of the use of "text node". A text node is a specific type of XML Node that can only contain character data. I think you mean that mainTerm has "mixed content", i.e. character data and elements.

Comment: update the question with your code

Comment: Yes, i mean "mixed content", but how i can get all data from mixed content to get result "Abasia (-astasia) (hysterical)"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ2XML. Just wrap your xml structure within a root node and fetch all title elements like this:

```
var xmlSrc = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><xml><mainTerm>
  <title> Abandonment </title>
  <see> Maltreatment </see>
</mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
  <title> Abasia <nemod>(-astasia) (hysterical) </nemod></title>
  <code>F44.4</code>
</mainTerm></xml>";

var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlSrc);
var mainTerms = xml.Root.Elements("mainTerm").ToList();
var titles = mainTerms.Elements("title").ToList();
foreach (var title in titles)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
}
```

The output is:

```
Abandonment 
Abasia (-astasia) (hysterical)
```

This is IMHO much easier than XPath and XmlReader.

---

Using the [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) function your **mainTerm** element does not need to be the root element:

```
var mainTerms = xml.Root.Descendants("mainTerm").ToList();
```

This line delivers all **mainTerm**'s at any level from the XML document!

Comment: Yes, maybe it's easy, but i have xml file with thousands of nodes and <mainTerm> is not even root element. My xmlReader works ok, except element like in my example... All what i need its fix that

Comment: I have extended my answer with a code example that retrieves all mainTerm's regardless of element position in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Read about xpath.

[xpath check if node has text](https://www.google.co.il/#num=30&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=xpath+check+if+node+has+text&oq=xpath+check+if+node+has&gs_l=hp.3.1.0i19l3j0i30i19.126671.133003.0.134611.37.32.2.3.3.1.223.2585.22j9j1.32.0...0.0...1c.1.14.hp.z4BiCbi_XHc&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k&fp=cb9ae01050cc027e&biw=1280&bih=699)

[xpath get node text](https://www.google.co.il/#num=30&safe=off&q=xpath+get+node+text&oq=xpath+get+node+text&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i30i19l2j0i5i30i19j0i8i30i19l6.64032.65968.0.66092.13.10.0.2.2.0.134.416.7j2.9.0...0.0...1c.1.14.serp.6abjcKe2694&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k&fp=cb9ae01050cc027e&biw=1280&bih=699)

[XmlReader xpath](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=XmlReader%20xpath&aq=f&oq=XmlReader%20xpath&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62.2363j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XmlDocument.  I find using that is much easier than xmlreader.
using your example...

```
1    <mainTerm>
2      <title> Abandonment </title>
3      <see> Maltreatment </see>
4    </mainTerm>
5    <mainTerm>
6      <title> Abasia <nemod>(-astasia) (hysterical) </nemod></title>
7      <code>F44.4</code>
8    </mainTerm>
```

Do something like this (Sorry, didn't have time to run this through a compiler... But this is the general idea)

```
XmlDocument example = new XmlDocument();

example.Load(StringWhereYouHaveYourXML); //You can also load Xml in other ways... check documentation

XmlNodeList mainTerm = example.SelectNodes("/mainTerm/"); //Now you have your list of Mainterms...
//Check for children in your nodes now...
forEach(XmlNode a in mainTerm){
   //check in the Title node for children that is
   XmlNode title = a.SelectSingleNode("/Title/");
   if (title.HasChildNodes){
      XmlNode abasia = title.SelectSingleNode("/nemod/");
   }
}
```

from there you can do what you want with the node.  But you now have it defined more concretely.